# Sending mail through JavaMail api using token

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am looking to send email through app from user's account through **JavaMail** api using google authentication token (instead of using a direct password).
  Here how I get the token after user picks an account:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("requestIdToken")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            //.enableAutoManage(this, MainActivity.this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN2) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            final GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            userMail = account.getEmail();
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        String scope = "oauth2:"+Scopes.EMAIL+" "+ Scopes.PROFILE;
                        accessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), account.getAccount(), scope, new Bundle());
                        Log.d("myapp", "accessToken:"+accessToken); // I get accessToken:ya29.Gl...
```

Now I use this for **JavaMail** api

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    //props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

    mSession  = Session.getInstance(props);
    try {
        transport = mSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", userMail, token);
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(mSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userMail, "test"));
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mEmail));
        msg.setSubject(mSubject);
        msg.setContent(mMessage, "text/html");

        //transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(BASE64EncoderStream.encode(String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", Utils.EMAIL, Utils.PASSWORD).getBytes())), 235);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
```

But I get exception:
*DEBUG SMTP: AUTH XOAUTH2 failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: OAUTH2 asked for more*

Question is:
Is there any issue with my code for **JavaMail** ? But more than that what I feel the scope which I defined to get access token, looks that's not enough to send a mail, but I am not sure.

If yes, is there any other way to achieve the same like using firebase token for JavaMail.

Comment: The JavaMail XOAUTH2 instructions are [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/OAuth2).  If that doesn't work there's probably something wrong with the way you've configured OAuth2 on the Google developer page, or in the way you're getting the access token in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I already got that link and tried the things mentioned there. I also think the same that the problem is with the token itself, but I am able to get the right user's mail, profile picture and the token id, but I am not sure about the 'Scopes' or how to have such token which can be used there. Whereas also there are some scopes (like composing mail) are restricted by Google.

Comment: @VickyKr Hi, were you able to resolve the problem? I'm facing veery similar problem. The difference is I am obtaining access token from spring security. I hope Mr. Shannon can pitch in here